# Allowing the access to the page only if redirected from another website with another domain

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pdo

I use specific page to give members special abilities on the web
I want members to be able to access this page only if they are redirected from another specific website.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are the database tags for?  You can't rely on a referral url for security, but maybe you can include an access token in the uri.

Comment: you can check for the referrer header, but this can easily be faked by the user. A secure token (generated by the target server, sent along from the source server - kind of handshaking thing) would be a better possibility

Comment: basicly the target server needs to ask the source server if this access is allowed/coming from him.

Comment: The problem is that the other web is not mine
|

Comment: It's a web to shorten links 
My web is all about going to the shorten link then being redirected back to get points. Once u collect specific points u get money]

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTP_REFERER

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

You can use it like this:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "specific website"){
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is referer is filled and sent by the client and isn't always filled by the browser, so this doesn't actually guarantee the client came from that site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this that way (but I suppose there are more possibilies):

Website A generates links with a random (but stored) token.
When Website B receives a request it askes website A if the token is from A, then allows the request.
If the token is wrong/outdated or not even there reject the request.

Comment: I can not make a check token as the second website is not mine
It's a web to shorten links My web is all about going to the shorten link then being redirected back to get points. Once u collect specific points u get money

Comment: Then I doubt there is a way to check for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use construction as @dieter-kräutl mentioned with `Referrer`.
But some browsers or their configuration can't guarantee that it will filled at all.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "specific website"){
  ...
}
```

Another option is to set some special cookie on this `specific website` and check if it is set on your site. This way has more chances to correctly, but it is harder to implement than previous option.